# How to drop multiple columns in dataframe, by using with loc and also with column names simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop few columns from dataframe, out of which few columns are in continuous manner which can be grouped using df.loc.

But I also have few column names which need be dropped using column names itself.

can someone help me in, using df.loc and column names simultaneously in the same drop sattement.

```
df_modified = df.drop(df.loc[:, 'Quarter of Joining': 'Age in Company (Years)'].columns, axis =1)
```

I also want to drop some more columns with their name i.e say 'DOB', 'Gender'

Comment: something like: `df.drop(df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc('Quarter of Joining'):df.columns.get_loc('Age in Company (Years)')+1].columns,axis=1)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion your solution is simpliest, here is alternative:

```
another = ['DOB','Gender']
m1 = (df.columns.values == 'Quarter of Joining').cumsum() != 0
m2 = (df.columns.values[::-1] == 'Age in Company (Years)').cumsum() != 0

df_modified = df = df.drop(df.columns[m1 & m2[::-1]].union(another), axis=1)
```

Your solution should be modified:

```
another = ['DOB','Gender']
c = df.loc[:, 'Quarter of Joining': 'Age in Company (Years)'].columns

df_modified = df.drop(c.union(another), axis=1)
```

Comment: I also want to drop some more columns with their name i.e say 'DOB', 'Gender'., which i should be able to achieve along with loc.